# Get Utterance value by passing utterance id in luis version 2 apis

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am working with luis version 2 apis in node js. I want to get api in which if i pass utterance ids: -12, -11 (returned from luis)etc. Then it should return utterance values, labeled intents and entities. 
I know ***Review labeled examples*** API is available in version 2 but it is giving all utterances by skip and limit options.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the result of the response and filter based on the utterance ID as you mentioned. An example is mentioned in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-node-add-utterance).

```
    "response": [
    {
        "value": {
            "UtteranceText": "go to seattle",
            "ExampleId": -5123383
        },
        "hasError": false
    },
    {
        "value": {
            "UtteranceText": "book a flight",
            "ExampleId": -169157
        },
        "hasError": false
    }
]
```

There isn't a specific API that does it.